# What is the difference between implication (->) and ##0 in SVA?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

What is the subtle difference between following statements

`a -> b` vs `a ##0 b`

in SVA (SystemVerilog Assertions)?

Answer (score 3):

First thing that you have to check is syntax of single implication operator that is `a |-> b`.

In SystemVerilog assertion there are two expressions.

1. `a ##0 b`
2. `a |-> b`

Actually, it looks like a similar in expressions. First of this expression is checking `a` is asserted(1) and after 0 clock cycle `b` is asserted(1) or not. Second expression is checking `b` is (on)asserted when `a` is asserted(1) then on same posedge `b` is asserted(1) or not.

Now, practically when verification engineers wrote this kind of assertions they take care of following things.

1. `a ##0 b`: **In this expression if `a` is not asserted then it shows failure.**

When `a` is asserted(1) and on same time stamp `b` is not asserted then also shows failure.

2. `a |-> b`: In this expression if `a` is asserted and `b` is not asserted then it will show a failure.

**If `a` is not asserted then it is not going to check whether `b` is asserted or not.** This behavior is different than `a ##0 b`.

If you apply different inputs data then you can see that **expression `a ##0 b` will give you more failure than `a |-> b`.** Reason for same is already explained above.

One more thing to note down is "The implication construct can be used only with property definitions. It cannot be used in sequences."

Thanks,

Ashutosh

Answer (score 1):

Your question illustrates the importance of the *implication operator* (`|->`). This example uses an implication operator and is useful:

`a -> b` means "if `a` is true then `b` should be `true`" (useful).

This does not and is usually not very useful:

`a ##0 b` means "`a` and `b` should be both true at all times" (not very useful).

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/47iN